# selenium: не получается нажать на кнопку на странице

Tags: python, selenium

У меня не нажимает кнопку, хотя класс кнопки не динамический, пожалуйста помогите

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import fresh_useragent
import undetected_chromedriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


def parsing_email_booking():
    try:
        service = Service(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
        driver = undetected_chromedriver.Chrome(service=service)
        driver.get("https://www.booking.com/searchresults.de.html?ss=Las+Vegas%2C+USA&label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaA6IAQGYAQe4AQfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQ2IAgGoAgO4Ar-t1qsGwAIB0gIkMmY5ZjExNWMtMmNmNi00NjJlLWEzZDYtY2JkNDc1M2Q4ZGYw2AIG4AIB&sid=d99a87ccb32937e6ef8f61065c9f9241&aid=304142&lang=de&sb=1&src_elem=sb&src=searchresults&dest_id=20079110&dest_type=city&checkin=2023-12-12&checkout=2023-12-13&group_adults=2&no_rooms=1&group_children=0")

        time.sleep(4)
#кнопка
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "a83ed08757 c21c56c305 f38b6daa18 d691166b09 ab98298258 deab83296e f4552b6561").click()

        for i in range(7):
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight)")
            time.sleep(1)

        time.sleep(5)

        #buttons_page = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "a83ed08757 c21c56c305 f38b6daa18 d691166b09 ab98298258 deab83296e bb803d8689 a16ddf9c57")

       # print(buttons_page)
        time.sleep(100)

       # with open("test.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        #    file.write(driver.page_source)

    except Exception as _ex:
        print(_ex)

    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
    #print(button_exit_cookies)


def main():
    parsing_email_booking()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Кнопка

```html
<button aria-label="Informationen zur Anmeldung ausblenden." type="button" class="a83ed08757 c21c56c305 f38b6daa18 d691166b09 ab98298258 deab83296e f4552b6561">
    <span class="eedba9e88a">
        <span class="fcd9eec8fb bf9a32efa5" aria-hidden="true">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M13.31 12l6.89-6.89a.93.93 0 1 0-1.31-1.31L12 10.69 5.11 3.8A.93.93 0 0 0 3.8 5.11L10.69 12 3.8 18.89a.93.93 0 0 0 1.31 1.31L12 13.31l6.89 6.89a.93.93 0 1 0 1.31-1.31z"></path>
            </svg>
        </span>
    </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Что это за кнопка? Не могу найти на сайте

Comment: Кнопка с окна которое просит зарегистрироваться, можете попробовать на кнопку переключения следующей страницы

Comment: Если не получается получить кнопку по css селектору, попробуйте получить ее по  XPATH

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="bodyconstraint-inner"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/button').click()